# Materialize sidenav not working on small devices

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am using Materialize with Django. Navbar is working fine on large screens, but sidenav is not working on small screens.

```js
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
 var sidenavInstance = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
```

```html
 <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger "> <i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
```

This is my code snippet.
I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'M_Sidenav' of null" on small screens.
Could anybody tell me why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you add the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked the JavaScript, for example through CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Also change

```
var sidenavInstance = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
```

to

```
var sidenavInstance = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
```

It is not clear from the official docs, but you have to pass options as second parameter. If you don't have any special options, then you should put `{}`.